# How do I center a navbar vertically along with page title?

Tags: html, css, web

Basically, I am trying to get my title and navbar vertically and horizontally centered with the title on top, but no matter what I do the navbar will not go under page title. They are just stacked horizontally.
I've tried line breaks and everything else I can, and It still won't work how I want it to. I know it's possible because I've seen it before on multiple occasions.

Page HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css">
    <title>comatose</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="subheader"><h1 id="title"><strong>PAGE TITLE</strong></h1></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#Invite">Community</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#Devs">Developers</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Page CSS:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400&display=swap');
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100vh;
}

#title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
}

.navlink {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlink a {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

I want all of the navlinks to be below the "PAGE TITLE" header.
I'm pretty sure it doesn't, but if it helps any: I use VSCode.
Edit - Also, I am new to web development so sorry if I did anything incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the gap you can add a margin in the #title like this:

```
#title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin: 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

because of `display:flex` css inside **#main**. it makes everything inside horizontally.

just add `flex-direction:column;` in **#main**

```
#main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    height: 100vh;
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@600&display=swap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400&display=swap');
body {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

#main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    flex-direction:column;
    height: 100vh;
}

#title {
    color: black;
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    margin-bottom:0px;
}

.navlink {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 5px;
    list-style: none;
}

.navlink a {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./home.css">
    <title>comatose</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="subheader"><h1 id="title"><strong>PAGE TITLE</strong></h1></div>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#About">About</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#Invite">Community</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#Devs">Developers</a></li>
                <li class="navlink"><a href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It works, but I feel like the gap is to big, and a bit off center. Is there a way I could shorten the height of columns or higher the count of them?

Comment: i added some margin-bottom css in #title and update the snippet. you can remove some margin in <ul> tag also. becasue h1, ul tag has some margin by default. so reduce according your choice. just add margin-top: 0px; in ul tag